# How can I integrate ion_auth library with CodeIgniter 3 HMVC?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

I used ion_auth before in my project and I have no problem with that. Now I have a project that has an HMVC approach.

Here's what i did in my setup.

1. I download ion_auth
2. I put the ion_auth folder in my module and load the sql
3. I auth load the ion_auth in my config

   - $autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'auth/Ion_auth', 'acl');
4. I modify the load config in the ion_auth library

   ```
   $this->load->config('auth/ion_auth', TRUE);
   $this->load->library(array('email'));
   $this->lang->load('auth/ion_auth');
   $this->load->helper(array('cookie', 'language','url'));

   $this->load->library('session');

   $this->load->model('auth/ion_auth_model');
   ```

And when I load ion_auth in my brower it says,

```
Unable to load the requested class: Ion_auth
```

And also I autoload the library in the Auth controller

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends MX_Controller {

    public $autoload = array(
        'libraries' => array(
            'auth/Ion_auth', 'form_validation', 'acl'
        ),
        'helper' => array(
            'url', 'language'
        )
    );

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();

        //$this->load->library(array('auth/ion_auth','form_validation'));
        //$this->load->helper(array('url','language'));

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters($this->config->item('error_start_delimiter', 'ion_auth'), $this->config->item('error_end_delimiter', 'ion_auth'));

        $this->lang->load('auth');
    }
```

But still same error.

I don't know what part I missed. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below document.

Document: http://avenir.ro/create-cms-using-codeigniter-3/securing-admin-area-ion-auth-library/

Answer (score 0):

For file structure will be as bellow. Auth file will be inside the library not in module

[image]